# If a function $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ is complex differentiable at a point $\mathbf{a}$, then are the Laplace equations automatically satisfied?

Tags: complex-analysis

If a function $$f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$$ is complex differentiable at a point $\mathbf{a}$, then are the Laplace equations automatically satisfied?

> We know that for complex differentiability the conditions are
>
> i) $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$ and
>   $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$ at the point $\mathbf{a}$
>
> ii) $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ are multivariable differentiable at the
>   point $\mathbf{a}$

If I differentiate the equation in $(i)$ w.r.t. to $x$ and $y$ and do a bit of manipulation then I end up with Laplace equations

i.e.

$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}=0$$

and $$\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial y^2}=0$$

However, I have a confusion here:

i) The partials $u_x$, $u_y$, $v_x$ and $v_y$ need not be continuous for $f(z)$ to be complex differentiable at $\mathbf{a}$. Just multivariable differentiability of $u$ and $v$ should suffice. According to this logic, complex differentiability does not necessarily imply that Laplace equations will be satisfied as $u_{xx},u_{yy},v_{xx},v_{yy}$ may not exist if the first order partials $u_x,u_y,v_x,v_y$ are not continuous.

ii) I have learnt that if a function is complex differentiable at a point $\mathbf{a}$ then it will be infinitely complex differentiable at that point too. By that logic it should mean $u_x,u_y,v_x,v_y$ are automatically multivariable differentiable at the point $\mathbf{a}$ i.e. $u_{xx},u_{yy},v_{xx},v_{yy}$ must exist automatically if the function is complex differentiable at point $\mathbf{a}$. According to this logic Laplace equations are automatically satisfied if the function is complex differentiable at point $\mathbf{a}$.

I think the second logic is somehow wrong but I'm not able to figure it out.

Comment: ii) is false. If you said instead "complex differentiable in an open set $U$", then yes, the function is in $C^\infty$ in $U.$

Comment: @zhw. Ah! That makes sense

Comment: Sufficient conditions for differentiability are satisfied not only by existence of CR equations, this partial derivatives must be continuous.

Comment: @ivanculet Continuity of partials is not necessary. Only multi-variable differentiability of $u$  and $v$ at $\mathbf{a}$ is needed (along with CR equations). Continuity of partials is a stronger condition than what is needed. [Well, at least that's what I've been told](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40554994#40554994).

Comment: Take for example $$\frac{{\bar{z}}^2}{z}$$ when $z\neq0$ and $$0$$ when $z=0$.

Comment: @Blue That is correct. $f(x+iy) = x^2\sin(1/x)$ shows this.